# C++ dynamic_cast on loop downcasting doesn't work as expected

Tags: c++

I am doing a program to learn template classes and `dynamic_cast` uses.
It uses a template class (`A`) to make a list of `B` class pointers. On the loop, it checks for each pointer if it points to a `C` object, and then execute its `Print()` method.

The code below should output `"C CALL"` two times, but it only outputs `"Start!"`. What am I missing?

```cpp
#include <vector>

template<typename widget_type>
class A
{
public:
    std::vector<widget_type*> value;

    virtual ~A() {}

    void Add(void* val)
    {
        widget_type* target = (widget_type*)val;
        value.push_back(target);
    }
};

class B
{
public:
    virtual ~B() {}
};

class C : B
{
public:
    void Print()
    {
        std::cout << "C CALL\n";
    }
};

class D : B
{

};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Start!\n";
    A<B>* index = new A<B>;
    C* c1 = new C;
    D* d1 = new D;
    C* c2 = new C;
    index->Add(c1);
    index->Add(d1);
    index->Add(c2);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        B* val = index->value[i];
        C* target = dynamic_cast<C*>(val);
        if (target)
        {
            target->Print();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are missing is knowing how to use a debugger that you can use to run your program, one line at a time, and see exactly what your program does. This is what a debugger is for. What did your debugger show you, when you ran this program? P.S. What you're also missing is undefined behavior. Every time you see `void *` in a C++ program which is ***not*** being used to interface with C code, it's almost always a guaranteed bug. And it is, in this case. C++ does not work this way (replacing `void *` with `widget_type *` in `Add()` will likely fix the bug).

Comment: I debugged it and it showed that dynamic_cast didn't return back a C* pointer, however, it showed that val was B* pointing to a C object. That is what really confused me

Comment: Casting to/from `void *` is equivalent to `reinterpret_cast` for the purposes here. You are effectively `reinterpret_cast`ing a class to its parent class, in two separate steps. That's a very doubtful proposition.

Comment: changing ```void *``` to ```widget_type *``` means I have to change ```index->Add(c1); ``` to ```index->Add((B*)c1); ``` and it produces the same result.

Comment: *"means I have to change index->Add(c1);  to index->Add((B*)c1);"* - No you don't. Not unless your compiler is broken or your actual code is vastly different. Edit: well, it would work correctly if you were doing public inheritance.

Comment: the conversion from ```D*``` to ```widget_type*``` exists, but it is not accesible with
```widget_type=B``` - Compiler and Debugger

Comment: changing to public inheritance worked. Thanks. How do I mark as answer?

Comment: Merely changing to public lets dynamic_cast to work but is not entirely correct answer about your code. C++ does not give guarantees that casting from C* to void* and then C-style casting to B*  results with correct B*. it just happens to work and that is actually bad when incorrect code appears to work.